# jsf cascading list

Tags: jsf

How do I cascade the lists so if user changes selection in selectedCategory list it should update the selectedTo list.

Here is my snippet:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectedCategory" value="#{converterBean.selectedCategory}">
  <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom"/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.categories}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneListbox id="selectedFrom" value="#{converterBean.selectedFrom}" size="5">
  <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.fromList}"/>
  <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory selectedFrom" render="selectedTo"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
<h:selectOneListbox id="selectedTo" value="#{converterBean.selectedTo}" size="5">
  <f:selectItems value="#{converterBean.toList}"/>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

I notice that it updates the selectedFrom list but does not cascade further to selectTo list.

As per suggestion to try render both selectedFrom and selectedTo for category selection the request posted from the page is:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/converter_web/faces/converter.xhtml HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Faces-Request: partial/ajax
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8081/converter_web/
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost:8081
Content-Length: 1253
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=DDDEA598A60CC468763C36B536513B41

converter_form=converter_form&converter_form%3AselectedCategory=temperature&converter_form%3AselectedFrom=mm&converter_form%3AselectedTo=cm&converter_form%3Avalue=0.0&javax.faces.ViewState=b%2BArKl5NJujWibUQzHf3dUG2JlT%2Bnq7KygA2%2FXpXXscCouBr5xT9Br%2BmoP78%2FvuPAYG%2Bi7Q0jFEKGqJpFgRo%2BDU4ZV251yac84pu3bZ71V9j%2BHvRPMkWw82S8q0v2p1jmn3msPXxvKrQQ1oVpr7pGBPXc2faQGXHW55Md%2BKSkspIgCxXx3x3T6NDaJ1%2BGTEFkyb1DE%2BdoQHQ4EjqV3jEC5mq56OlsHgEmkQ8TVCQM%2FPmAfUBWiQEHqBYzohXNfFpO3kfdrKjeTrq648UtGPYU88VJ9mtIOptYEfwFKN9y%2FG9MOBKEfRZ9XlJz2bPt1zmATIg3iRT1W7YVtmHq7e9g%2FUxsM82duMxFUWhoFPHfrFk4tt48LFH29Hk60y3eeFxqtg7g1JxPD1aQrLN9sxBduS53nFWObCms1YU40uvMT2yjX0kp4wM8YwqT2jTFDtLHcVBide1RGTnzFGzjOrbCJ8rIEmWfPa1yUMkXRBBsgpKWFIl0ueBQiCT%2BDoD9UXlNOQGS%2F5tIdP%2BVTO%2FkWiBo5X99SpKwKY8%2B2pqzJKDrPRXIwci52Wi%2Fo%2Fw%2B0TkpnVrtDaDl7w2eYjmq7bYZFRDjWy3Jtgc5V1DUF%2BhX3Bfiq7l%2Fq5YL4DYx0NBI2esfJ0LTFCqXu8aCk%2BWOPOWnOCSGA5Y9EGUXgzV6q%2Fp%2FFWa8Kj8E%2FeoB380eFwXAEiyyRGv&javax.faces.source=converter_form%3AselectedCategory&javax.faces.partial.event=change&javax.faces.partial.execute=converter_form%3AselectedCategory&javax.faces.partial.render=converter_form%3AselectedFrom%20converter_form%3AselectedTo&javax.faces.behavior.event=valueChange&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true
```

We would expect only selectedCategory be send but its sending all form fields in ajax call.  It though calls getCategories(), getFromList(), getToList() but when it calls getToList it uses category=temperature and from=mm.  from=mm is what is passed in POST request as selectedFrom=mm.

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added ajax listener as below so indicate that category change is being invoked so that getFromList will set selectedFrom to new item from its list instead of one being posted.  Then getToList will find correct category and from unit to query its to list.

```
<f:ajax execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom"></f:ajax>
```

to

```
<f:ajax listener="#{converterBean.categoryChanged}" execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom selectedTo"></f:ajax>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change this:**

```
  <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom"/>
```

**To this:**

```
  <f:ajax execute="selectedCategory" render="selectedFrom selectedTo"/>
```

Comment: Baydogan I have tried it and that causes only ONE request with current category and old selectedFrom to be posted.  What we want is using selectedCategory fill selectedFrom list and then using selectedCategory and new selectedFrom query selectedTo.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your concrete functional requirement, but wouldn't that just be a matter of adding `selectedFrom` to the `execute`? I'm also surprised to see the ajax listeners which should be responsible for populating the dropdowns are missing, this suggests that you're doing business job in getter methods, which is considered a Bad Thing in JSF.

Comment: @BalusC as I understand adding fields to execute merely means that we want them posted in request.  so when I submit category I am posting only selectedCategory while when I submit from unit I pass both selectedCategory and selectedFrom.   When category changes the from unit needs to be refreshed.  When a from unit selection changes to unit needs to be refreshed. to give analogy its like country->state->city cascading.  As far I know the render methods are place where we can call business logic on service tier.